# Does Linux Mint have /etc/debian_version?

Tags: linux-mint, version

I am trying to write a script which works based on the knowledge that each Linux Mint release was based on a particular Ubuntu release.

However, I do not want to install Linux Mint to verify that, but instead let the users of the script test it, if they need it.

Can I rely on the presence of `/etc/debian_version`, though? I am doing this in order to detect Debian and its derivatives. It works reliably on Debian and Ubuntu, but does Linux Mint have this file?

Note: I am aware of `lsb_release` and I am using that in order to figure out more details later on. But the existence of `/etc/debian_version` is a way to make assumptions about certain things before even checking for and invoking `lsb_release`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in @kirill-a's answer, `/etc/debian_version` should be present in any Debian derivative.

Another useful approach to find out information on the current Debian-based distribution and its "ancestry" is `dpkg-vendor`; for instance,

```
dpkg-vendor --derives-from Debian
```

should succeed on any Debian derivative (and on Debian itself),

```
dpkg-vendor --derives-from Ubuntu
```

should succeed on any Ubuntu derivative (and on Ubuntu itself), etc. A distribution is considered a derivative of itself as well as of its parents, so Ubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu and of Debian.

`dpkg-vendor` is shipped in `dpkg-dev` so that needs to be installed for the command to be available, which reduces the usefulness somewhat.

Comment: Wow, didn't know of that one. However, before your `if` (and assuming Bash) I'd always do `type dpkg-vendor > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "No dpkg-dev!"; exit 1; }`, which tests for the availability of the program. And it turns out this is part of `dpkg-dev` which is one of the packages that gets installed via `build-essential`, but it's not part of a base installation. Still, very cool idea and method.

Comment: Note that, like `/etc/debian_version`, that reports information stored in the `base-files` package which on Mint comes straight from Ubuntu. `/etc/lsb-release`, `/etc/issue`... also come from `bash-files`, but the `mintsystem` package registers `File` triggers for them and overwrites them whenever they're modified by another package.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as in any Ubuntu derivative, this file is present.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Well, I know that theoretically that should be the case. My question, however, was **whether it is the case** on Linux Mint specifically. The well-known problem is that in theory practice and theory are the same; but in practice they often divert. My uncertainty in response to your answer stems from a generic answer to a specific question.

Comment: Awesome, this screenshot is proof enough. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I'm running Mint 19

```
$ lsb_release -d 
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara

$uname -a
Linux mymc 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP ...

$ cat /etc/debian_version
buster/sid
```

This: `cat /etc/debian_version | grep -o '[0-9]'| head -1|sed -e 's/ //'`
should tell you what version of debian is used, but mint obscured it.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not add anything to the existing ones and it doesn't even answer the question (apart from showing that `/etc/debian_version` is indeed present on your system).

Comment: Your last paragraph is only correct for stable Debian releases; `buster/sid` is a perfectly valid entry for Debian and derivatives, Mint isn’t obscuring anything.