# How can I recognize that a certain Linux distribution is based on Debian, looking at file structure?

Tags: linux, debian, distributions

I have an unknown (let's assume `uname -a` returns nothing) Linux distribution I have root access to.

How can I verify, looking at file structure, that it is based on Debian?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6345/4671

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view if a file called `/etc/debian_version` exists.

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
wheezy/sid
```

If it exists, you also can see the version of debian. Also distributions like Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and so on, which are based on Debian have that file.

Actually most distributions have a release file you can also try and see what comes out:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not concern the filesystem structure, but you could check whether the `apt-get` (Debian) or the `yum` (non-Debian) package management commands are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to first look if a `/etc/debian_version` exists. It should be there if it's a Debian based distro.

Usually, looking for `apt` files could give a clue. For instance, look at the conf in `/etc/apt/` or if a `/var/cache/apt/` exists.

Unforunately, `apt` can be setup on another distro, or an admin could have set dummy files or directories for some compatibility reasons...

As stated in [one answer of this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182409/does-linux-mint-have-etc-debian-version), the best would be to try to run:

```
 dpkg-vendor --derives-from Debian
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existance of `/etc/debian_version`.

Or you could use `lsb_release -a`.